# How to run a particular test case in protractor using command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I have successfully created my test cases in protractor. I would like to run a particular test case from command line. My conf.js file has all the spec.js in the suit.

When I run protractor conf.js I want to run only the spec I type in the command line.
Example 
if i have 3 test cases A.js B.js and C.js
and in test suite has all the 3 testcases in my conf.js
and when i run `protractor conf.js -A.js` it should run the testcase A.js.

Please help me out how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can simple execute particular spec by just passing --specs  as parameter.

> protractor config.js --specs test1.js

otherwise

You can create seperate suite for each spec files in config.js and pass --suite suitename to execute specifi test.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to run specific test case in protractor. Just rename describe to ddescribe and only test under ddescribe group will run. Also you can rename it to iit and only this one test case will run.

Comment: can you give an example for the same?